# How to display picture(jpg) with TDBImage from TBlobField?

Tags: delphi

I want to display image from database that was set to blobdata type.
But when i pair with TDBImage show error

[image]

anyone can help?

Comment: I appreciate that you are new to SO and have not yet learned how to do stuff, but please read: [**how to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Spend some time to digest it completely. We are eager to help you but we simply can not read your mind, neither your screen nor your code. You are probably doing something wrong but we can't know what, because you have not provided any useful information to evaluate.

Comment: TDBImage supports only bitmap. I have been using EDBImage: http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/22742

Comment: It sounds like you're just assigning TDbImage to a blob field of a dataset, correct?  The Delphi documentation explains that this requires a field of ftGraphic type.  While you can use blobs to store images, it would be easier to load into a TImage, and there are samples of how to do that here on SO, here is on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655031/how-to-display-blob-image-from-database-in-the-tadvstringgrid-with-the-help-of-d

Comment: Note that starting in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, `TDBImage` now has "*direct support for JPEG and PNG graphic formats*", it is not limited to just BMP anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I have been using this code to load any kind of image from Database.

```
uses
  Vcl.Graphics, PNGImage, JPEG;

function GetHeader(const AFile: string; const AByteCount: integer): string;
const
  HEADER_STR = '%s_HEADER: array [0 .. %d] of byte = (%s)';
var
  _HeaderStream: TMemoryStream;
  _FileStream: TMemoryStream;
  _Buf: integer;
  _Ext: string;
  _FullByteStrArr: string;
  _ByteStr: string;
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  if not FileExists(AFile) then
    Exit;

  _HeaderStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  _FileStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    _FileStream.LoadFromFile(AFile);
    _FileStream.Position := 0;
    _HeaderStream.CopyFrom(_FileStream, 5);
    if _HeaderStream.Size > 4 then
    begin
      _HeaderStream.Position := 0;
      _ByteStr := '';
      _FullByteStrArr := '';
      for i := 0 to AByteCount do
      begin
        _HeaderStream.Read(_Buf, 1);
        _ByteStr := IntToHex(_Buf, 2);
        _FullByteStrArr := _FullByteStrArr + ', $' +
          Copy(_ByteStr, Length(_ByteStr) - 1, 2);
      end;
      _FullByteStrArr := Copy(_FullByteStrArr, 3, Length(_FullByteStrArr));

      _Ext := UpperCase(ExtractFileExt(AFile));
      _Ext := Copy(_Ext, 2, Length(_Ext));
      Result := Format(HEADER_STR, [_Ext, AByteCount, _FullByteStrArr]);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(_FileStream);
    FreeAndNil(_HeaderStream);
  end;
end;

function GetImageFromBlob(const ABlobField: TBlobField): TGraphic;
CONST
  JPG_HEADER: array [0 .. 2] of byte = ($FF, $D8, $FF);
  GIF_HEADER: array [0 .. 2] of byte = ($47, $49, $46);
  BMP_HEADER: array [0 .. 1] of byte = ($42, $4D);
  PNG_HEADER: array [0 .. 3] of byte = ($89, $50, $4E, $47);
  TIF_HEADER: array [0 .. 2] of byte = ($49, $49, $2A);
  TIF_HEADER2: array [0 .. 2] of byte = (77, 77, 00);
  PCX_HEADER: array [0 .. 2] of byte = (10, 5, 1);

var
  _HeaderStream: TMemoryStream;
  _ImgStream: TMemoryStream;
  _GraphicClassName: string;
  _GraphicClass: TGraphicClass;
begin
  Result := nil;

  _HeaderStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  _ImgStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    ABlobField.SaveToStream(_ImgStream);
    _ImgStream.Position := 0;
    _HeaderStream.CopyFrom(_ImgStream, 5);
    if _HeaderStream.Size > 4 then
    begin
      if CompareMem(_HeaderStream.Memory, @JPG_HEADER, SizeOf(JPG_HEADER)) then
        _GraphicClassName := 'TJPEGImage'
      else if CompareMem(_HeaderStream.Memory, @GIF_HEADER, SizeOf(GIF_HEADER))
      then
        _GraphicClassName := 'TGIFImage'
      else if CompareMem(_HeaderStream.Memory, @PNG_HEADER, SizeOf(PNG_HEADER))
      then
        _GraphicClassName := 'TPNGImage'
      else if CompareMem(_HeaderStream.Memory, @BMP_HEADER, SizeOf(BMP_HEADER))
      then
        _GraphicClassName := 'TBitmap'
      else if CompareMem(_HeaderStream.Memory, @TIF_HEADER, SizeOf(TIF_HEADER))
      then
        _GraphicClassName := 'TWICImage'
      else if CompareMem(_HeaderStream.Memory, @TIF_HEADER2, SizeOf(TIF_HEADER2))
      then
        _GraphicClassName := 'TWICImage'
      else if CompareMem(_HeaderStream.Memory, @PCX_HEADER, SizeOf(PCX_HEADER))
      then
        _GraphicClassName := 'PCXImage';

      RegisterClasses([TIcon, TMetafile, TBitmap, TJPEGImage, TPngImage,
        TWICImage]);
      _GraphicClass := TGraphicClass(FindClass(_GraphicClassName));
      if (_GraphicClass <> nil) then
      begin
        Result := _GraphicClass.Create; // Create appropriate graphic class
        _ImgStream.Position := 0;
        Result.LoadFromStream(_ImgStream);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(_ImgStream);
    FreeAndNil(_HeaderStream);
  end;
end;

{ --- Usage --- }

procedure TForm1.BitBtn5Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  qImage.Close;
  qImage.ParamByName('prm_id').Value := Edit2.Text;
  qImage.Open;
  Image1.Picture.Assign(GetImageFromBlob(qImageany_kind_image));
  Image1.Picture.SaveToFile('C:\Users\Edijs\Desktop\test.' +
    GraphicExtension(TGraphicClass
    (GetClass(Image1.Picture.Graphic.ClassName))));
end;
```

Answer (score -2):

In your case you can use just the `*.bmp` files , to use `*.jpeg` files

**You must use JPEG unit :**

```
Uses
JPEG;
```