# "Bitmap image is not valid" error message when connectinDBImage to an image field (OLE object) in MS access

Tags: delphi-2010

I have a MS access table with a "picture" field that Im trying to access using an ADOtable, Datasource and DBimage. The .jpg images are entered as OLE-objects into the access table. whenever I try to display the image by selecting "picture" in the datafield property of the DBImage, the error "Bit map image is not valid" pops up

Is there any way that I can fix this , or is there any way that I can display an image using an access table

Thank you x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display picture(jpg) with TDBImage from TBlobField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188245/how-to-display-picturejpg-with-tdbimage-from-tblobfield)

Comment: Prior to Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, `TDBImage` only supported BMP images.  In Tokyo, [TDBImage was updated](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/What%27s_New#Database_improvements) with "*direct support for JPEG and PNG graphic formats*". So prior to Tokyo, the only way to display a JPG from a DB is to load the image manually into a `TJPEGImage` and then use `TImage` instead of `TDBImage` to display it.  Or find a 3rd party `TDBImage` replacement that supports JPGs.