# Extracting information from a BLOB field

Tags: xml, delphi, firebird

I have a table which has a BLOB field, this field is used to store xml files, now I want to find a way to load the information back to xml files (FileSystems).

Comment: I don't know Delphi, but I assume it will be the same (or similar) as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863169/load-and-save-image-from-blob-field-in-delphi-using-firebird

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you select your data:

```
select xmlfile from myTable
```

When accessing it you simply cast the field to be a `TBlobField`:

```
  TBlobField(ADOQuery.FieldByName('XmlFile')).SaveToFile(myFileName);
```

Here I just used a `AdoQuery` as `TDataset`, but it can be anything else.

Comment: @ Jens , Thanks alot, your answer seems to be working.